# Minimum Pumping Length

Tags: pumping-lemma

What is the minimum pumping length of following language
L=10 (11* 0)* 0

I have read a statement like this

> s = xyz = 10100 where x=10,y=10 and z=0 such that xyiz∈L (that is 10(1∊0)*0  )
>   Well it looks Minimum Pumping length is 5 , But it is not, We can repeat y any time (or it should be) and y≠≠ ∊ that mean we cannot use 3 or less length string from L for pumping , So y can be 10 (minimum) so minimum string S we using for pumping is 10100  of length 5, but length 4 string can not generated from the given language (that's not our fault). So we can say we use 4 or more length string s for pumping that belongs to L. Therefore pumping length is 4

But ,
I am confused with this . 
y=10 , SO what made the author say pumping length of three or less possible ? it has to be two or less. Don't it ?
if pumping length of 4 is possible it has to be accepted by Language L . Doesn't it ? Please help me find the minimum puping length of this question

Comment: *SO what made the author say pumping length of three or less possible*  he said it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

The minimum pumping length is a minimum constant `C` such that any string of the language with length greater or equal `C` can be pumped (as far as i remember). The author of the citation said that minimum length of **existing** string that can be pumped is 5 for the regular expression but there are no strings with length 4 in the language so it is **safe to say** that minimum pumping length is 4 because it appropriate for the definition.

Comment: What is the string with length 4 here ? I didn't get you .
if such a language exists then what is its x y z part ?

Comment: There are **no** stirngs with len 4 in the language it is a gap in it. So 4 length **fits** well to the definiton. We can pump each string with length >= 4